# getAttribute value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller... I'm trying to get the `name` and `rating` attibute from an HTML input, but I get the error `TypeError: angular.element(...).getAttribute is not a function`

```
app.controller('courseReview', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.rateThis = function rateThis(el){
    var elName = angular.element(el).getAttribute('name');
    var rating = angular.element(el).getAttribute('rating');
    document.getElementById(elName+'Rating').value = rating;
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="courseReview">
  <!-- radio input -->
  <input class="star-5" id="wstar-5" rating="5" type="radio" name="welcome" ng-click="rateThis(this)"/>
</div>
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the documentation "https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element", to get attribute of an element you need to use

```
.attr('name');
```

in place of

```
.getAttribute('name');
```

**Important**

You are passing `this` in your html, here `this` will not pass the DOM element to the function, rather it will refer to the scope. To pass the current element pass `$event`

HTML Change

`ng-click="rateThis(this)"` to `ng-click="rateThis($event)"`

JS Change

```
$scope.rateThis = function rateThis($event){
    var elName = angular.element($event.target).attr('name');
    var rating = angular.element($event.target).attr('rating');
    document.getElementById(elName+'Rating').value = rating;
}
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQlEG33VvE72dOvqwnpy?p=preview

Comment: This gives undefined for me

Comment: Shouldn't ng-onclick be ng-click?

Comment: You can use  $event as well - For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQlEG33VvE72dOvqwnpy?p=preview

Comment: Excellent, appreciate your help with this - still learning to think the Angular way!